# SCCM report not loading or its taking forever to load

Tags: sql-server, sccm

thanks for all help i got for SCCM related tables,views iam at end of of project.
iam working on dashboards and it was working pretty fine till sunday

iam getting data in query designer like this

[image]

iam adding in piechart like this

[image]

but while running report it taken forver for loading only single piechart
what could be reason?
can you please help me
[image]

Comment: How many rows are there in your resultset? It doesn't make sense to create a pie chart with more than 20 rows in the resultset.

Comment: too many like 40 and in some there are more, i told client he wants piechart, wont be able to view with so minute details

Comment: issue is with less no of slices too its giving problem

Comment: so did I get this right. Without the pie chart, with the data shown as a table it is fast but as soon as you use a chart it is slow? It is safe to say it is not a problem with the query itself?

Comment: select distinct(v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED_Alias.NormalizedVersion),count(v_R_System_Valid_Alias.Netbios_Name0)as modelcount
         FROM fn_rbac_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED(@UserSIDs) v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED_Alias
         INNER JOIN fn_rbac_R_System_Valid(@UserSIDs) v_R_System_Valid_Alias on v_R_System_Valid_Alias.ResourceID = v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED_Alias.ResourceID   
 where productName0 like '%Google Chrome%'
--          order by v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED_Alias.NormalizedName, Publisher, Version

Comment: group by v_GS_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE_CATEGORIZED_Alias.NormalizedVersion

Comment: its working in Dev, piv but not in prod

Comment: i  increased timeout as well, noluck